# Unwanted bottom margin on floated image in short parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

I have a page which will only be viewed in mobile Safari, with the following HTML markup:

```
<blockquote>
  <p><img src="..."/> A paragraph...</p>

  <p>...</p>

  ...
</blockquote>
```

And CSS like this:

```
blockquote {
  border-left: 1px solid #888;
}

blockquote img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

When the paragraph text is long enough, this produces the desired effect:

```
| IMAGE  A paragraph, blah blah blah...
| IMAGE  blah blah blah...
| IMAGE  
|        More paragraph, blah blah blah...
| blah blah blah, blah blah blah...
```

For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/KDYCN/

The margin at the right and the bottom of the image is desired to provide needed whitespace between the image and the text.

However, when the paragraph text is short, it produces an unwanted margin at the bottom. Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but the border line on the left makes this glitch stand out like a sore thumb:

```
| IMAGE  A paragraph, blah blah blah...
| IMAGE  blah blah blah...
| IMAGE  
|
```

For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/KDYCN/1/

Any ideas on how to solve this, other than to make all quotes long enough? :) Even a JavaScript soluton is acceptable, though not ideal. Thanks!

Comment: Please can you provide some screen shots and perhaps a working example in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: And a link to an image that you're using, or a defined size of the image(s) you might be using.

Comment: Yes, just added two jsfiddle examples. What an awesome website!

Comment: The image has a fixed width, but I don't know the height in advance. The page is dynamically generated though, so I can apply an individual style to each image with a known height, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
blockquote img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

to this:

```
blockquote img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I removed this and it seemed to do the trick:

```
blockquote:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The reason was this hidden thing was after the image with clear:both, which made the blockquote tall enough to contain both text and image.  See it in action by giving the blockquote a border temporarily:

```
blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #00ff00;
}
```

I like neon green because it's easy to see and typically nothing should be that color, so it's also easy to see if I left my debug code in place.

Comment: That would remove the bottom margin, which is "desired to provide needed whitespace between the image and the text".

Comment: The things is, I want the blockquote tall enough to contain both the image and the text. I just don't want the extra margin at the bottom of the image when it isn't needed.

Comment: Then pull the 20px margin off the blockquote style instead

Comment: Then I would have a border on the left of the space between the blockquote and the following paragraph.